# How to disable USB charging entirely on Windows?

Tags: windows, usb

I have a desktop running Windows 7 where I want to forbid people from connecting USB and charge through. I did set the registry value of HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\UsbStor\Start to 4 and did disable all **USB Root Hub** in the Device Manager, still phones connected can charge. How can I stop that?

Answer (score 4):

You can’t. It’s hard-wired on the motherboard. If you don’t want people to access the PC’s hardware and/or connectors, lock it away.

Comment: never expected that!

Answer (score 1):

You COULD disable it. If you want the port to not work at all just unplug the header cable. If hardwired, plug the port or remove the port completely. If you want to choose to be able to enable the port, wire a switch in to the power feed only you know about.

Comment: Oh so there's no software way to do it?

Comment: Of course not, you don't need software to charge your phone by plugging into a wall socket right? The two outer pins deliver 5V to the device, nothing you can do to stop that unless you start desoldering